# Доступ к экземпляру класса из любого места

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, классы

Добрый день. Есть сайт (точнее панель управления) на Django. При запуске веб-сервера должен запускаться демон (создаваться экземпляр класса, который при инициализации запускает бесконечный цикл в новом потоке. Сейчас это происходит в models.py приложения). В дальнейшем (по запросу пользователя из панели) необходимо передавать/получать данные от этого демона при помощи его методов.

Соответственно возникает вопрос: как можно передать ссылку на экземпляр класса в другие модули, чтобы взаимодействовать с ним?

P.s. Вариант класть нужные данные/запросы/etc в базу данных не предлагать, т.к. вся эта система работает на raspberry pi и SD-карту лишний раз трогать не хочется. Кроме того есть операции, в которых нужна мгновенная реакция от демона.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

UPD. В общем ответа я так и не нашел, зато нашел более-менее адекватный выход из ситуации. При инициализации веб-сервера запускаем демон, а затем управляем им при помощи redis. Его принципиальное отличие в том, что он хранит данные в оперативной памяти а не на диске, что, учитывая специфику sd карт, немаловажно.

Answer (score 1):

> Соответственно возникает вопрос: как можно передать ссылку на экземпляр класса в другие модули, чтобы взаимодействовать с ним?

В новый инстанс интерпретатора - никак, насколько знаю.

Вам нужен [IPC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5), если так необходимо срочное реагирование, то надо поднимать слушающий сокет/файл-пайпу. У меня на реализацию такой штуки при моих бедных познаниях в питоне и диком рефакторинге ушла неделя-две.

Comment: Нет. Возможно, кто-то из нас что-то не понял. Запускается вебсервер. Инициализирует Django: считывает settings.py, models.py, etc. Во время инициализации models.py одного из активных приложений создается экземпляр моего класса, который в методе __init__ создает новый поток управления запуская в нем бесконечный цикл. Затем управление возвращается Django и он проводит инициализацию дальше.

Все, что мне нужно - это лишь передать в определенный класс/метод ссылку на запущенный экземпляр демона. В дальнейшем для управления демоном нужно лишь вызывать методы этого экземпляра. Ничего более.

Comment: @rdvlip я в питоне не совсем свой, разве в этом случае джанго не будет висеть бесконечно?

А для реализации  можно использовать модуль Queue. Создаете перед выполнением метода init, передаете в новый поток, в классе с обычном потоком создаете геттер для этой очереди. После этого демон висит на очереди и собирает задания, а все остальные потоки туда скидывают сообщения.

Comment: 1. Нет, не будет. Почитайте про модули multithreading и multiprocessing.
2. Стоит внести ясность. Класс, экземпляр которого запускается при инициализации Django не сам запускается в другом потоке, а лишь является оболочкой для него. Т.е. методы этого класса при вызове принимают аргументы, а затем отправляют их в очередь на переработку демону. Синхронизируется все это при помощи сигналов, но это уже совсем другая история.

По поводу предложения использовать очереди. А в чем смысл то? Ну то я буду передавать экземпляр очереди, а то экземпляр своего класса. Разницы никакой.

Comment: Мне просто нужен способ передать определенному методу ссылку на объект. Не важно какой: своего класса или класса Queue.

Comment: Ну тогда создайте classmethod у своего класса или сделайте его синглтоном.